Thread to detect language or caps lock change triggers only the first time
I am trying to build a program that makes an announcement whenever you change language on your keyboard and whenever you change the case state.
The issue I have is that it announces in the start and then whenever I change language or caps lock it doesn't continue to announce.
Would appreciate any help or insights.
import pyttsx3
import ctypes
import win32api
import threading
import time

# Initialize text-to-speech engine
engine = pyttsx3.init()

# Initialize global variables for current language and case
current_language = None
current_case_state = None

# Function to get the current keyboard layout
def get_keyboard_language():

    try:
        user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
        curr_window = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
        thread_id = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(curr_window, 0)
        klid = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(thread_id)
        language_id = klid & (2 ** 16 - 1)

        # Language mapping based on primary language identifier
        languages = {
            0x0409: "English",  # English (US)
            0x0C0C: "French",  # French (Canada)
            0x0407: "German",  # German (Germany)
            0x0410: "Italian",  # Italian (Italy)
            0x0A0A: "Spanish",  # Spanish (Spain)
            0x0408: "Greek",  # Greek (Greece)

            # Add more language codes if needed
        }

        return languages.get(language_id, "Unknown")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in get_keyboard_language: {str(e)}")
        return "Unknown"


# Function to check if caps lock is on
def is_capslock_on():
    try:
        return win32api.GetKeyState(0x14) == 1
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in is_capslock_on: {str(e)}")
        return False

# Function to announce the language and case


def announce_language_case():
    global current_language, current_case_state
    try:
        while True:
            language = get_keyboard_language()
            case_state = is_capslock_on()
            case = "uppercase" if case_state else "lowercase"

            if language != current_language or case_state != current_case_state:

                current_language = language
                current_case_state = case_state
                print(announcement)  # For debugging purposes
                engine.say(announcement)
                engine.runAndWait()

            time.sleep(0.1)  # Check every 0.1 seconds

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in announce_language_case: {str(e)}")

# Start a thread to announce language and case changes
thread = threading.Thread(target=announce_language_case)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

# Keep the main thread running
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)  # Keep the main thread alive

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopping...")

